# "広める" instead of "広まる" or "広められる" in this context?

Tags: transitivity

I came across this sentence:

> 来年は、踊り子三百人をフランスに招いて、阿波踊りの魅力をもっと**広めて**いくようです。

Stripping the sentence to basic sentence structure:

> 魅力を**広めて**いく。

How can that be grammatically correct?

As "広める" is transitive with an obvious object, there must be an *actor* as the subject? I don't see one. You can sort of hide the *actor* using passive voice. This seems grammatically correct to me:

> 魅力が**広められて**いる。

Or, isn't the intransitive verb also an option:

> 魅力が**広まって**い*る*。

In English, the given sentence sounds to me like:

> ??? is widening the appeal of the dance.

But, who is widening the appeal? Don't you have to say:

> The appeal of the dance is widening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, there has to be an actor and there is. The same actor as for 招く earlier in the sentence.

> 阿波踊りとは、徳島県を発祥とする盆踊りです。日本三大盆踊りで、日本の伝統芸能の一つとして、日本全国からたくさんの観客が訪れます。
>   その阿波踊りが、フランスのパリで初めて開催されました。このイベントは、日本在住のフランス人ジャーナリストが阿波踊りを自分の国に届けたい思いで、１０年かけて実らせました。
>
> パリでは、大人から子供まで阿波踊りの魅力を味わうことができ、会場は熱気に包まれたそうです。
>
> **来年は、踊り子３００人をフランスに招いて、阿波踊りの魅力をもっと広めていくようです。**
>   ([Source](http://newsinslowjapanese.com/2015/10/12/japanese-listening-166-awa-odori-in-paris/))

Here's the whole context I found. From the earlier context, the unspoken actor in the final sentence must be the event organisers (who else would do these actions?).

So, "It appears they [the event organisers] will bring 300 dancers to France next year and spread the appeal of awa-odori even more."

Comment: An "泡踊り" would be much more popular than an "阿波踊り"!

Comment: Indeed, one line example sentences are not very useful in learning Japanese grammar. thanks.

Comment: @david 「泡踊り」って何ですか？　げっ！下ネタ！？

Comment: @choco いやいや。下品じゃないはよ。今、日本はまだ近代化しつつあっても、賑やかな外国人が多いすぎの東京と離れたら、伝統的な自然環境が多い所がある。そこには、泡踊りをやる温泉があるだぞう。きっと、私の広島の近くには一つがある。見ながら、色々感激する。また、見にいけばいいのにさ。

Comment: @choko 僕もてっきり下ネタかとｗｗｗｗ

Comment: @choco wow. I just talked with a native speaker and was told how inappropriate the kanji I used for "あわ" was. And then my response in comments section... If a mod wants to delete this question, that is fine / preferred.